# Having trouble joining friends world in Minecraft PE using wifi

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, wifi

I'm trying to play with my friend and were running into some difficultly. Both our wifi's are connected to the same network, literally right beside each other. We both have multiplayer on. We both have the newest update of Bedrock. Neither of us can connect to each other's worlds. We have even tried on different devices. When I go to my settings in my world it says friends of friends, but won't let me change it, saying I need to sign in to my Microsoft account. Well, my friend and I don't have a Microsoft account, or we couldn't sign at the moment... but I'm pretty sure all you really need is the same wifi connection, right? I'm having some real trouble and it would mean the world to me if you could help!

Comment: I believe in order to play multiplayer in Bedrock, you would indeed need to create a Microsoft account.

Comment: hmm... Did they change that just this last update? Because I remember when you just needed wifi??

Answer (score 0):

You do need a Microsoft account,
I've tried playing on my phone with a ps4 user, and we had to sign in to our Microsoft accounts.